# Yad gui to replace a picture in a directory?

Tags: gui, yad

I need a yad script to perform 2 functions.

**1. Image slect**

I have a picture in a directory : /usr/share/picture.jpg

I want to create a yad gui that asks the user to select his own picture and then yad replaces the existing picture with the picture the user selected.

**2. Input Box**

I have a file with values in it for example : /usr/share/file
the values are : technical=enginefault

I need to have an input box that replaces the original value with the value the user inputs.

So basically a Yad Gui that has both an input box and an image selection box, the image replaces the existing one and the input replaces the text inside the existing file.

anyone that can assist me please ?